# HTML Input Time, where min is pm (late) and max is am (early)

Tags: html, time, max, min

I have an input box, with a type of "time". I want to have a late time (23:00pm) as a min value, and an early time (6:00am) as a max value - creating a range of 23pm - 6am. (ie. 11pm, 12pm, 1am, 2am, 3am, 4am, 5am, 6am).

I've tried using Javascript, although I want to use it as a last resort. I don't want the native component to show up with values that I don't want the user to select (for example, on mobile devices).

Setting the 'min' value to 00:00:00 and the 'max' value to "06:00:00" works as intended. It's when the min value is before midnight it becomes an issue.

I'd expect the min and max values to create a range, but that doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in MDN docs:

> Unlike many data types, time values have a periodic domain, meaning
>   that the values reach the highest possible value, then wrap back
>   around to the beginning again. For example, specifying a min of 14:00
>   and a max of 2:00 means that the permitted time values start at 2:00
>   PM, run through midnight to the next day, ending at 2:00 AM.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#max

That said, it seems like this is not working properly in Chrome 76.0,
after a simple test with a `min` value greater than the `max`, all times fail the validation and the form just don't work.

I suggest https://timepicker.co/ since it will work cross browser.

```css
input:invalid+.validity:after {
  content: '✖';
}

input:valid+.validity:after {
  content: '✓';
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="time1">3:00 to 6:00: </label>
  <input type="time" min="3:00" max="6:00" name="time1" required>
  <span class="validity"></span>
  <hr>
  <label for="time2">23:00 to 6:00: </label>
  <input type="time" min="23:00" max="6:00" name="time2" required>
  <span class="validity"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: I've marked this as the 'right answer'. Simply put - it looks like the periodic domain restricts you from having a min time greater than a max time. My solution was to use moment.js and create a select / option box dynamically using a while loop. Unfortunately the timepicker.co has the same problem, you can't put a range in where the min is greater than the max.

Comment: You could also use a combination of type time and type date.

Answer (score 0):

I experimented a little using the `:invalid` CSS pseudo-class but I couldn't come up with anything.

Note that in **Firefox** (unlike **Chrome**), the browser does not include up and down arrows on any `<input type="time">` form element, so the `min` and `max` attributes have no effect.

I note that **Mozilla Developer Network** says the following:

> By default, `<input type="time">` does not apply any validation to
>   entered values, other than the user agent's interface generally not
>   allowing you to enter anything other than a time value. This is
>   helpful (assuming the time input is fully supported by the user
>   agent), but you can't entirely rely on the value to be a proper time
>   string, since it might be an empty string (""), which is allowed. It's
>   also possible for the value to look roughly like a valid time but not
>   be correct, such as 25:05.

**Source:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#Validation